# Could not be found or it does not implement IController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am working on an application which contains some ASP Classic, ASP.Net and ASP.Net MVC pages.
The main landing page of the application is developed in MVC and a sub directory which contain simple ASP.Net code.

I am getting a error when calling any ASP.Net page from sub directory.

The controller for path '/subdirectory/Recent.aspx' could not be found or it does not implement IController

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your request is handled by the MVC handler before the ASP.NET, thus it will complain that you don't have the controller for subdirectory.

Phil Haack provided an overview on how to use the routing for ASP.NET webform:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/11/using-routing-with-webforms.aspx